# Надписи в профиле — два года спустя

Tags: дефект, локализация, нытьё

Думал, само рассосётся, если долго не смотреть в их сторону, но что-то оно не торопится.

Открываем вкладку [Активность в профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/squidward?tab=summary), смотрим на кнопки сортировки/группировки/фильтрации (некоторые для контекста):

- "голоса" (votes) — сортировка по оценке по убыванию. Звучит логично.
- "текущие" (activity) — сортировка по дате последнего изменения поста по убыванию. Не знаешь — не догадаешься. Рядом с "новые" логичнее видеть "активные", например.
- "новые" (newest) — сортировка по дате создания по возрастанию. В меру нормально.
- "недавние" (recent) — сортировка по дате создания (связи юзер-знак) по возрастанию. Зачем разные надписи для одного и того же — мне не понять. В оригинале такая же глупость.
- "добавлен" (added) — сортировка по дате создания (связи пост-избранное-юзер) по возрастанию. В принципе нормально, но почему-то хочется "добавление" (сортировка по "дате добавления", а не по "дате добавлен").
- "сообщение" (post) — группировка репутации по дням и постам. Руки чешутся назвать "сообщения", равно как и в оригинале "s" добавить.
- "голос «за»" (upvotes) — фильтрация по голосам +1. Зачем повторять слово "голос" — не знаю. Хватило бы просто "за". У надписей в списке тоже.
- голос «против» (downvotes) — аналогично.
- переоткрыть (reopen) — фильтрация по голосам за переоткрытие. Соседстует рядом с "удаление", "восстановление" и "закрытие", поэтому логично назвать "переоткрытие".

О прочем в профиле. Надпись "След. знак" выглядит странно. Я вижу, что места под полную надпись навалом. Справа от надписи что-то длиннее счётчика бывает? Зачем сокращать?

В надписи "Посмотреть профиль на Мете →" перенос оказался прямо перед стрелкой, хотя места достаточно.

Переходим на список тревог.

- Надпись "полезные" в списке фильтров справа — это нормально. Надпись "полезные" под каждой отдельной полезной тревогой — это ненормально. Должно быть "полезная". Аналогично со "спорные" и прочими.
- "Тревоги типа «невежливость» и «оскорбления»" — странная надпись, типы какие-то, и вообще в список не вписывается. Должно быть что-нибудь вроде "тревоги на невежливость и оскорбления".
- "тревоги на сообщениях", "тревоги на комментариях" — мне решительно не нравится предлог. Почему не "тревоги на сообщения" и "тревоги на комментарии"?
- От замены общеупотребительной "жалобы" на экзотическую "тревогу" у меня отдельная попаболь, но не будем о грустном.

Я закончил.